# Unlock records submitted through Approval Process in single transaction

Tags: apex, approval-process

I want to unlock records submitted through Approval Process and I found that the Approval Class has methods which allows this.

However,i'm confused by the results of the isLocked property in trigger context and in future(i.e. separate transaction).

```
    for(Case newCase : newCases) {
        Set<Id> caseIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        Boolean b = Approval.isLocked(newCase.Id);
        //this prints false when called from trigger while prints true when treated in 
        future context
        System.debug('locked? '+b);
        if(Approval.isLocked(newCase.Id)) {
            caseIdSet.add(newCase.Id);
        }
    }
    if(!caseIdSet.isEmpty()) {
      Approval.unlock(caseIdSet);
    }
```

I'd like to understand if i'm missing something here. Would definitely prefer to unlock in one transaction rather than doing the same on a separate transaction.

Appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: so what is the question - are you saying that unlocking only works in future and not synchronously?

Comment: I think the record is not yet submitted to the approval process, as you check the case using the developer anonymous window it will show the record is now locked. Approval processes and Triggers are generally not going to be run in a common transaction. I think you can decide in Apex trigger whether you want to submit the record for approval or not.

Comment: @cropredy according to the results it looks like that indeed. Please note that here the scenario is that the user submits a record for approval from UI and record lock is an initial submission action, i'd like to unlock it.  To solve this I have tried 1. unlocking in trigger context (after update) & 2. calling a future method from after update. What i've found in debug log is that the record stays unlocked throughout the trigger context(isLocked = false), in a separate transaction(i.e. future) record is locked(isLocked = true) and then Approval.unlock(caseIds) works.

Comment: Maybe you should frame this is a self-answered question and add to the Community KB